# Basic Shaped Products Design Patents

Tags: patentability, design-patent, design, patent-design

I am looking into filing for a design patent, and have been consulting with a patent lawyer. The product I would like to patent is somewhat of a combination of a few basic shapes that I fear have a high chance of being rejected due to being too simple, not elaborate enough. But since I am still a novice in this arena, and before I shell out a few grand to file, I figured I would take the temperature of those who have more experience.

I will post a few examples to better represent what I am getting at.

Would these have a high chance of being rejected? Low (average chance)? Or too vague to determine.

[image: oval]

[image: oval1]

[image: sphere]

[image: sphere1]

[image: pyramid]

[image: pyramid1]

Comment: Design patents are for the ornamental design of functional objects. Is there a function?

Comment: Also, don’t post a drawing of a design you actually want to patent.

Comment: The question is not simplicity but prior art. Are similar shapes known?

Comment: One thing that is also important is the identity of the functional item. Don't tell us! But a lion head shaped lamp base is different from a very similar lion head shaped book end.

Comment: My design is unlike any other designs patented (that I'm aware of after extensive google patent searches). But I cant determine if it is unique enough to be patented. The samples I posted are random, but combinations of simple shapes, unique, but basic. There of course is functionality, but I don't think that would matter for design patents... Shape is shape, regardless of its use, correct?

Comment: Is there no solution cut and dry? Perhaps any patent examiners would best be able to answer this

Comment: Your best bet is to consult a patent attorney or agent.

Comment: I think the question as posed is unanswerable. Whether or not anything is patentable is specific to the thing itself and prior art. You aren't going to get a design patent on a ball shaped ball. You might get a design patent on an ornamental graphic printed on a ball if it is distinct from other prior art.

Comment: This is a very simple shape https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/3e/c0/70/259c2332419080/USD610380.pdf Notice the claim is for "An ornamental design of a table top, substantially as shown as described". The type/function of the article of manufacture (table top in this case) is an important part of the claim - a shape is not a shape. Another important patenatblity issue with designs is that the ornamentation to be protected, must, itself, be not dictated by functionality.  Yes, I am the agent that prosecuted this design patent.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, it is not how simple or fancy it is. It needs to be a novel and non-obvious ornamentation of *something*. A design patent must relate to an "item of manufacture". A shape is not a shape. Your examples are meaningless without being something but please don't post your actual ideas.

What is patented is is a specific kind of [bowl](https://patents.google.com/patent/USD684822S1), a [toilet bowl](https://patents.google.com/patent/USD703797S1), [table top](https://patents.google.com/patent/USD610380S1) or a [doorstop](https://patents.google.com/patent/USD653532S1). The claim and title are for a thing. From these examples you can see that a design can be simple.

Comment: thank you for clarifying